# Wrapping a Package/procedure in PLSQL using object name

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a package, which is already created in DB.

How to wrap the package by inputting the object name without inputting the total script?

Comment: Can you define "wrap"? What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Do you have any code to demonstrate?

Comment: @Ben, "wrapping" is a method for obfuscating PL/SQL code in an Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DBMS_DDL.Wrap to wrap packages that are n the database, but it requires that you read their definition (using DBMS_Metadata for example) to pass it to the procedure, then take the wrapped output and execute the wrapped create package code (using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for example).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/wrap.htm#BEHGEBGI